# Invalid Hook call error in React when applying authorization

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to look for answers to this one and am coming up blank. The goal is to have user auth go through on a form, that is in a modal. All of the UI stuff works great, until I try and apply the Auth. I am not sure how I would have ended up with mismatching versions of React, so I do not believe that to be the problem. What can be done about this?

```
const LoginModal = (props) => {
  const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const [validated] = useState(false);

  const [login, { error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER);

  const userInputHandler = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setLoginData({ ...loginData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    try {
      const { data } = await login({
        variables: { ...loginData },
      });
      Auth.login(data.login.token);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    setLoginData({
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center md:z-100 min-h-screen bg-rose-50">
        <form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="relative flex flex-col m-6 space-y-10 bg-white shadow-2xl rounded-2xl md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:m-0">
            {/* left side */}
            <div className="p-6 md-20">
              {/* top content */}
              <h2 className="h2 mb-5 text-4xl font-bold cursor-pointer">
                Login
              </h2>
              <p className="max-w-sm mb-12 font-light text-gray-600">
                Login to see your saved activities!
              </p>
              <div className="space-y-4">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="w-full space-y-4 p-6 border border-gray-300 rounded-md placeholder:font-light "
                  placeholder="Email"
                  onChange={userInputHandler}
                  value={loginData.email}
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="w-full space-y-4  p-6 border border-gray-300 rounded-md placeholder:font-light "
                  placeholder="Password"
                  onChange={userInputHandler}
                  value={loginData.password}
                />
              </div>

              {/* Middle Content */}
              <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between mt-6 space-y-6 md:flex-row md:space-y-0">
                <div
                  className="font-thin text-cyan-700 cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={props.SwitchModal}
                >
                  Sign Up
                </div>
                <button disabled={!loginData.email && loginData.password} className="w-full md:w-auto flex justify-center items-center p-6 space-x-4 font-bold text-white rounded-md px-9 bg-cyan-700 shadow-cyan-100 hover:bg-opacity-90 shadow-sm hover:shadow-lg border transition hover:-translate-y-0.5 duration-150 ">
                  <span>Next</span>
                  <FaHandPointRight />
                </button>
              </div>
              {/* Border */}
              <div className="mt-12 border-b border-b-gray-300"> </div>
              {/* Bottom Content */}
              <p className="py-6 text-sm font-thin text-center text-gray-400">
                You can also login with
              </p>
              <div className="flex flex-col space-x-0 space-y-6 md:flex-row md:space-x-4 md:space-y-0">
                <button className="flex items-center justify-center py-2 space-x-3 border border-gray-300 rounded shadow-sm hover:bg-opacity-30 hover:shadow-lg hover:-translate-y-0.5 transition duration-150 md:w-1/2 ">
                  <FaFacebook />
                  <span className="font-thin">Facebook</span>
                </button>
                <button className="flex items-center justify-center py-2 space-x-3 border border-gray-300 rounded shadow-sm hover:bg-opacity-30 hover:shadow-lg hover:-translate-y-0.5 transition duration-150 md:w-1/2 ">
                  <FcGoogle />
                  <span className="font-thin">Google</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* right side  */}
            <img src={Chairman} alt="" className="w-[430px] hidden md:block" />
            {/* Close button */}
            <div className="group absolute -top-5 right-4 md:top-4 hover:cursor-pointer hover:-translate-y-0.5 transition duration-150">
              <FaWindowClose
                onClick={props.onShowModal}
                className="group-hover:text-gray-600"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginModal;
```

[image: Error in Console]

Mutations:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
      user {
        _id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_USER = gql`
  mutation addUser($username: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
    addUser(username: $username, email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
      user {
        _id
        username
        email
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const SAVE_TASK = gql`
  mutation saveTask($input: SavedTaskInput) {
    saveTask(input: $input) {
      _id
      username
      email
      savedTasks {
        activity
        type
        participants
        price
        link
        key
        accessibility
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_TASK = gql`
  mutation removeTask($key: String!) {
    removeTask(key: $key) {
      _id
      username
      email
      savedTasks {
        activity
        type
        participants
        price
        link
        key
        accessibility
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Does it tell you in the error message that the error is coming from this ```LoginModal``` component? because I don't see anything wrong here. It's probably coming from the Auth file.

Comment: Yes it says the `LoginModal` I thought this looked right as well

Comment: Please show entire error with stack trace.

Comment: Posted above! I went overboard on the size clearly

Comment: Do you run a conditional hook in `useMutation`? The error is thrown in the `LoginModal` but the stacktrace also mentioned `useMutution`

Comment: I didn't, but I posted my Mutations anyway